# Distributing a given amount over a list of negative values from bottom to top in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table of negative values for a given date like this:

```
------------------
| date | deficit |    budget: 100
|----------------|
|01.01 |   -5    |
|01.02 |   -7    |
|        .       |
|        .       |
|20.12 |   -8    |
|30.12 |   -6    |
------------------
```

I also have a fixed number, lets just call it budget and say its 100.

Now I want to use my budget to cancel out the negative values, for example I reduce my budget from 100 to 95 and write 0 in the table in the row with date 01.01, instead of 5.

Like this:

```
------------------
| date | deficit |    budget: 95
|----------------|
|01.01 |    0    |
|01.02 |   -7    |
|        .       |
|        .       |
|20.12 |   -8    |
|30.12 |   -6    |
------------------
```

**I want to do this sequentially from the lowest date to the highest date, and if I run out of budget just leave the negative values at the end that I cannot fill anymore.**

In the end, it would look like this, assuming we reached the 20.12 entry with a budget of 6, thus not being able to cancel out the negative value completely and running out of budget

```
------------------
| date | deficit |    budget: 0
|----------------|
|01.01 |    0    |
|01.02 |    0    |
|        .       |
|        .       |
|20.12 |   -2    |
|30.12 |   -6    |
------------------
```

How would I do that? I know how I would do this in an imperative language, but how do you ensure in which order it substracts and change the statue of the sum in a mostly declarative language? 
I'm using oracle.

EDIT:

Here is what I want to do given in imperative pseudo code:

```
*Asuming deficits are already ordered by date
foreach deficit of deficits
  if (budget - deficit) >= 0
    set deficit = 0 
    set budget = budget - deficit
  else 
    set deficit = budget - deficit   
    set budget = 0
  end if
```

So I basically need this but in SQL code.

Comment: More examples might help - or rather that one example extended to more rows; if I'm following you, your second row ends up as 0 and budget is reduced to 88, and then that continues... so showing enough data to expend the budget would be useful. And you just want to show the final result set really - here you're just explaining the steps, you don't want to see them, right?

Comment: Ok, I have expanded the examples I provide in the question

Comment: And yes, I am just explaining the steps, I care only for the end result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few ways to approach this, but you can use windowed analytic functions to get a running total of the deficit and how much of the budget has been spent. To get the final number you want you could use something like:

```
greatest(deficit,
  sum(deficit) over (order by date_col)
    + least(100, - sum(deficit) over (order by date_col)))
```

or perhaps a bit more clearly:

```
case
  when sum(deficit)
    over (order by date_col rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) <= -100
  then
    deficit
  else
    sum(deficit) over (order by date_col)
      + least(100, - sum(deficit) over (order by date_col))
end
```

The `sum(deficit) over (order by date_col)` gives you the running total, in date order, of the deficits. For the first date that is calculated as -5; for the second as (-5 + -7) = -12; etc.

The `least(100, - sum(deficit) over (order by date_col)))` gives you budget used up to and including the current date, but capped at 100. For the first date that is `least(100, - (-5))` which is 5; for the second it is `least(100, - (-5 + -7))` which is 12; by the 20th it is `least(100, - (-102))`, so you get the lower of 100 and 102 - so capped to 100. (You could do that as `greatest(-100, sum(deficit) over (order by date_col)))` if you prefer, and then subtract that in the last step instead.)

When that is added to the running total of the deficit, the first few rows cancel out and you get zero. For the 20th, the deficit total is 102 and the capped value is 100, so you end up with -2. For the 30th though, that would give you 100 - 108, so -8 instead of the -6 you actually want. That's where the `greatest(deficit, ...)` comes in. Up to the 20th that doesn't change the answer; `greatest(-8, 100 - 102)` is still -2, because -2 > -8. For the 30th you have `greatest(-6, 100 - 108)` is -6, because -6 > -8.

Demo with some sample data and showing some of the working:

```
-- sample data
with your_table (date_col, deficit) as (
            select date '2020-01-01', -5 from dual
  union all select date '2020-01-02', -7 from dual
  union all select date '2020-01-03', -50 from dual
  union all select date '2020-01-04', -32 from dual
  union all select date '2020-01-20', -8 from dual
  union all select date '2020-01-30', -6 from dual
)
-- actual query
select date_col, deficit,
  sum(deficit) over (order by date_col) as sum_deficit,
  least(100, - sum(deficit) over (order by date_col)) as budget_used,
  greatest(0, 100 + sum(deficit) over (order by date_col)) as budget_left_1,
  100 - least(100, - sum(deficit) over (order by date_col)) as budget_left_2,
  greatest(deficit,
    sum(deficit) over (order by date_col)
      + least(100, - sum(deficit) over (order by date_col))) as new_deficit_1,
  case
    when sum(deficit)
      over (order by date_col rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) <= -100
    then
      deficit
    else
      sum(deficit) over (order by date_col)
        + least(100, - sum(deficit) over (order by date_col))
    end as new_deficit_2
from your_table
order by date_col;
```

which produces:

```
DATE_COL      DEFICIT SUM_DEFICIT BUDGET_USED BUDGET_LEFT_1 BUDGET_LEFT_2 NEW_DEFICIT_1 NEW_DEFICIT_2
---------- ---------- ----------- ----------- ------------- ------------- ------------- -------------
2020-01-01         -5          -5           5            95            95             0             0
2020-01-02         -7         -12          12            88            88             0             0
2020-01-03        -50         -62          62            38            38             0             0
2020-01-04        -32         -94          94             6             6             0             0
2020-01-20         -8        -102         100             0             0            -2            -2
2020-01-30         -6        -108         100             0             0            -6            -6
```